# Loading big image on web page as background

Tags: html, css, image, load, onload

I have image *(Dimensions - 1600 × 585, File size - 292 KB, MIME type - image/jpeg)* with natural size **1600 x 585 pixels** and on page it takes size **1903 x 580 pixels**.

**Problem** : on page load this image appears as *small* (not as natural size) and then *stretche out* on page.
When connection is not fast, it looks not good.

How can i fix this problem?

```
img {height: 580px;position: absolute;width: 100%;z-index: 0;border: 0;vertical-align: top;}
```

Comment: have you tried putting the image in body, in css?

Comment: @wribit em... maybe there is a problem... i add image in tag <img/>.. i will try to do it as background image. thanks

Comment: Also add 'position:fixed' ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solutions in my case is :

```
img{height: 580px; position: fixed; width: 100%;z-index:0;top: 0;left: 0;}
```

I try every other answers, but every have some 'defects' (image starting loading as with width and then streches).
Thanks @Dylan de St Pern for suggestion, this helps `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

Update answer :

```
.yourDiv {
   background-image: url('../path/to/your/image');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: fixed or scroll;
   background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, tick the arrow. These people are giving you answers and getting nothing in return.

Answer (score 1):

use this function with it while calling the image in css as background

```
  background: url("ur image") no-repeat cover ;
```

there are different functions 
for me cover works fine...

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
    body{
        background: url(../images/page_background.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
body{background-image:url('root/myimage.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; margin:0;}
```

ALSO:

set a background color for if the image takes a moment to load:

```
body{background-color:#333;}
```